# How don't show ValidationSummary when there is a propety error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginVM)
    {
        var isLogin = SessionContext.Instance.AuthMgr
            .Login(loginVM.Email, loginVM.Password);

        if (!isLogin)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "wrong email/passord");

            return View(loginVM);
        }

        User user = SessionContext.Instance.AuthMgr.User;

        return RedirectByUser(user);
    }
```

My View Code:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "alert" })
```

The problem is: When I got a property error in my model, `VaidatonSummary` wrapper shouldn't be shown.

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors alert"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
```

My problem was described here: [Why is ValidationSummary(true) displaying an empty summary for property errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107263/why-is-validationsummarytrue-displaying-an-empty-summary-for-property-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "alert" })
```

From the view

Comment: I can't remove it because I need to show ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "wrong email/passord");