# ModelState.IsValid is false prior to validation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, modelstate, custom-model-binder

We wrote a custom model binder that overrides the `CreateModel` method of the `ComplexTypeModelBinder` so that we can have `injection` into our `ViewModels` instead of having to pass the `injected clients` and `repos` to our `model` from the `controller`.

For example, for a `model` like this:

```
public class ThingViewModel 
{
    public ThingViewModel (IThingRepo thingRepo) {}
}
```

In our `controller` we can do:

```
public class ThingController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(ThingViewModel model) => View(model);
}
```

And this works pretty well, here's the override part of the `custom model binder`:

```
protected override object CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var model = bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(bindingContext.ModelType);
    if (model == null)
        model = base.CreateModel(bindingContext);
    if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Method == "GET")
    {
        bindingContext.ValidationState[model] = new ValidationStateEntry { SuppressValidation = true };
    }
    return model;
}
```

Pretty straightforward stuff.

The problem, is that in our `GET action methods`, if we use a `ValidationSummary` in the `view`, because `validation` was not run, the `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`, even though there are `0 errors`... this causes the `ValidationSummary` to show up empty with a red border around it. An annoying work-around for this is to call the `ModelState.Clear() method` prior to sending the `model` into the `view`. Can I somehow change it so that `IsValid` is defaulted to `true` when `validation` has not been run yet? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to IoC model binding.  MVC has an issue of still rendering an empty container for your validation summary, even if you have no validation errors.  Two possible work arounds include:

1. Create a partial that wraps the validation summary.  In that partial, check for any errors in your model state before rendering the validation summary.  Use that partial in place of where you would have used the stand alone validation summary.
2. Add some CSS that hides the containing div if it does not contain any populated or visible list items.  If there are no visible error list items, the container's display should be none.

See this for additional info: [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107263/why-is-validationsummarytrue-displaying-an-empty-summary-for-property-errors)

Comment: Only problem with 2 is that it always has an `<li />` whether there are errors or not.